# How to sum the column with matching characters in a specific location?

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to add the output of du for all sub folders with the certain same subfolder characters.

I have tried (example)

```
du -s /aa/bb/cc/*/ | sort -k2.11,2.14
```

where I got the output sorted

```
2000 /aa/bb/cc/1234/
1000 /aa/bb/dd/1234/
2000 /aa/bb/ff/1234/
2000 /aa/bb/cc/5678/
2000 /aa/bb/dd/5678/
3000 /aa/bb/ee/5678/
1000 /aa/bb/gg/5678/
```

Now I would like to add all the ones with 1234 and 5678

Expected result

```
5000 -- 1234

8000 -- 5678
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `awk` to store all the content of first filed into an array `a` using key of 2nd last field.

```
du -s /aa/bb/cc/*/ | sort -k2.11,2.14 |awk -F'/' '{a[$(NF-1)]+=$1}END{for(i in a) print a[i],i}'
8000 5678
5000 1234
```

Comment: This seem to work thanks. But the output is not sorted, how can I sort it?

Comment: The sort of the `du` results can be removed, and `| sort -n` can be appended.